# How to ideally improve React performance: componentWillReceiveProps vs shouldComponentUpdate

Tags: performance, reactjs

I'm wondering which technique is best to improve a React application's performance. I learned about the Component lifecycle methods `componentWillReceiveProps` and `shouldComponentUpdate` but I'm not really sure which one I should ideally implement to avoid unwanted re-rendering.

So is it best to implement both or just one of them?

Also, I don't understand why `shouldComponentUpdate` receives the `nextProps` if `componentWillReceiveProps` already (should) handle(s) those.

Comment: Performance improvement starts with profiling. Once you what slows you down you can make a focused effort to optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

```
componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    console.log("componentWillReceiveProps");
    return false; // This will not terminate further control flow in this component.
}

shouldComponentUpdate(props, newState) {
    console.log("shouldComponentUpdate");
    return false; // This terminates further control flow in this component.
}
```

Based on condition you can return boolean value from the `shouldComponentUpdate` method. If you are returning `false` it will not call the `componentWillUpdate()` method.

Comment: I don't think `componentWillReceiveProps` receives a second (`newState`) argument. Also don't think it should return a boolean.

Comment: @Koen you were right. It doesn't have the second argument. In the case of `return` statement, I was trying to explain `componentWillReceiveProps` is not the place for skip rendering.

Comment: _"componentWillReceiveProps might get called, even if the props didn’t change"_ - [from this](https://reactjs.org/blog/2016/01/08/A-implies-B-does-not-imply-B-implies-A.html)

Comment: I knew all that. The question was what is the best way to optimize performance. I read by default `shouldComponentUpdate` returns `true` (so re-rendering happens on any props update and state update, even without a change). I also read to avoid deep equals in `shouldComponentUpdate` so not sure how to handle this ideally.

Answer (score 0):

Use PureComponent instead of Component when you need behavior described in your question. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent